# Use date parameters with a PowerBI "direct" query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I created a 'direct' query in PowerBI, that I would like to modify to support two date parameters: `StartingDate` and `EndingDate`:

[image]

I modified the query to reference the two parameters:

```
= Sql.Database(
  "10.0.0.4", 
  "PHCS_UAT", 
  [Query="
    SELECT  *#(lf)
    FROM    TABLE#(lf)
    WHERE   StartTime BETWEEN '" & StartingDate & "' AND '" & EndingDate & "'", CreateNavigationProperties=false]
)
```

This generates an error: `We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Date.`.

What's the preferred way to convert a date to a string?

I would to add 23h 59m 59s to the `EndingDate` parameter.  I could do this in the SQL (`select dateadd(second,-1,cast( dateadd(day,1,cast(getdate() as date)) as datetime))`), but it might be cleaner using a PowerBI function.  Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
StartTime BETWEEN '" & Text.From(StartingDate) & "' AND '"
                     & Text.From(EndingDate) & " 23:59:59'"
```